# How to understand this statement Ext.form.Field.prototype.msgTarget = 'side' in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, prototype

I am learning ExtJS2.2.1 recently. I am so confused about it. I know it's about quick tips when you enter an error in the form. But it's just a simple use, I want to have a deeper understanding. While I couldn't find any relevant information when I tried to find the answer on the official document(visit: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/2.3.0/#!/api/Ext.form.Field).

And I looked at the revevant source code in Field.js as follows:

```
@cfg {String} msgTarget The location where error text should display. Should be one of the following values
(defaults to 'qtip'):
Value         Description
qtip:         Display a quick tip when the user hovers over the field
title:        Display a default browser title attribute popup
under:        Add a block div beneath the field containing the error text
side:         Add an error icon to the right of the field with a popup on hover
[element id]: Add the error text directly to the innerHTML of the specified element
msgTarget :  'qtip',
```

I found this is about the prototype in JavaScript. But I don't understand more about prototype and what I want to know is how to learn ExtJS when I can't get the answers on the official document.

Comment: What you want here to know.And if you dont get answers on sencha official doc you will have to post question here or debug sencha code to find out rootcause of issue or either find any workaround.

Answer (score 0):

msgTarget is a config to let you decide how you want to show validation error occurred in that component.
I have created a fiddle showcasing this and it used NumberField to demonstrate this.

Read [msgTarget](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/api/Ext.form.field.Number.html#cfg-msgTarget) and check code. Hope you will get it.

```
Ext.require('Ext.form.*');

Ext.onReady(function() {
  Ext.createWidget('form', {
    renderTo: 'sampleform',
    title: 'Validate two fields with dynamic error catching',
    bodyPadding: 20,
    width: 400,
    fieldDefaults: {
      anchor: '100%'
    },
    items: [{
      xtype: 'label',
      id : 'errorLabelId',
      cls : 'errorLabelCls',
      width: 100,
      height: 20
    }, {
      xtype: 'numberfield',
      anchor: '100%',
      name: 'bottles',
      fieldLabel: 'Bottles of Beer',
      value: 99,
      maxValue: 99,
      minValue: 0,
      msgTarget: 'qtip'
    }, {
      xtype: 'numberfield',
      anchor: '100%',
      name: 'bottles',
      fieldLabel: 'Bottles of Beer',
      value: 99,
      maxValue: 99,
      minValue: 0,
      msgTarget: 'title'
    }, {
      xtype: 'numberfield',
      anchor: '100%',
      name: 'bottles',
      fieldLabel: 'Bottles of Beer',
      value: 99,
      maxValue: 99,
      minValue: 0,
      msgTarget: 'under'
    }, {
      xtype: 'numberfield',
      anchor: '100%',
      name: 'bottles',
      fieldLabel: 'Bottles of Beer',
      value: 99,
      maxValue: 99,
      minValue: 0,
      msgTarget: 'side'
    }, {
      xtype: 'numberfield',
      anchor: '100%',
      name: 'bottles',
      fieldLabel: 'Bottles of Beer',
      value: 99,
      maxValue: 99,
      minValue: 0,
      msgTarget: 'none'
    }, {
      xtype: 'numberfield',
      anchor: '100%',
      name: 'bottles',
      fieldLabel: 'Bottles of Beer',
      value: 99,
      maxValue: 99,
      minValue: 0,
      msgTarget: 'errorLabelId'
    }]
  })
})
```

Check [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uamd423v/3/)

Play with all NumberFields and try entering invalid values (values greater than 99) and check errormessage shown. Hope it clears your doubt.